# Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I'm getting below error while running my Springboot application

> Error creating bean with name 'userRepo' defined in  defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'

```java
package <mypackage>;

import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User,Long>{
    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

I'm using `Java 17`, `Spring-boot 3.1.2`, `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `spring-boot-starter-security`

I've tried to check if my database server is running & correctly configured in `application.properties` file but i've not found any problem there

Comment: Are you defining your own `EntityManagerFactory` in your configuration?

Comment: @M.Deinum No even then i am getting issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue when I tried to upgrade from Springboot 2.x.x to 3.x.x. Finally figured out it is due to wrongly defined naming strategy. In my case I updated below line in my application.yml file and solved the issue.

Previously I had

```
physicalNamingStrategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
```

Then I changed it to

```
physicalNamingStrategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
```